# Validate props with PropTypes if it have dynamic name

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

In my react app I have component, in which i pass props. Props can have different names. I want validate them with PropTypes (should be `PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.object]`). How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at these PropTypes [validating examples.](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes)

You could write a custom validator similar to the example:

```
// You can also specify a custom validator. It should return an Error
// object if the validation fails. Don't `console.warn` or throw, as this
// won't work inside `oneOfType`.
customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
    return new Error(
      'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
      ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!